# Splash screen in EGL and opengl es2

Tags: multithreading, opengl-es-2.0

I need to add a splash screen to an opengl es2 application which uses EGL to interact with the windowing system.
The application takes a few seconds to load resources, establish connections and whatnot, and during this time I need to draw a splash screen. The window and EGL context is the first thing that is created so I have everything I need to do this.

I've seen a few posts around the web that describe how to create another context that can be used in a different thread but there's very little detail really.

The question is, do I need to create the GL resources that will be used in the worker thread itself? For example, does the shader need to be compiled and linked in the worker thread or can it be compiled/linked in the main thread? What about the thread's context itself? Can this be created in the main thread? Does everything need to be created in the worker thread or does it not matter?

Comment: All OpenGL ES operations should be done from it's thread. This includes GLSurfaceView, GLRenderer etc.

Comment: What's a GLSurfaceView? The app runs on linux/X11 not Android. So do I also need to call eglMakeCurrent() from the main thread? What does "all opengl ES" operations mean? I obviously have to draw from the worker thread so some gl operations must be on the thread. Do you mean EGL operations?

Comment: I've been testing stuff while waiting for a reply and what I think you are suggesting here seems to be correct. Whenever I attempt to compile a shader or call eglMakeCurrent in the thread I get a horrible crash with no backtrace.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you were working with Linux. Though, AFAIK, any EGL operations should be done from rendering thread.

Comment: Also, according to [this](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/5577-OpenGL-ES-calls-across-multiple-threads) post on Khronos forums: `Binding 2 different contexts in 2 different threads to the same surface is NEVER allowed.
Binding 2 different contexts in 2 different threads to 2 different surfaces MAY be allowed, but MAY fail.` That post is 9 years old though and things may have changed during the time.